# How to pass a python list back to C program

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, python-2.7

My C program calls a python module to perform some tasks, and returns a tuple back from python to C using `PyArg_ParseTuple`. Adding another layer to the python module results in a list sometimes being apart of the returned tuple. Is there a method of parsing the values of this list, and storing them into a C array or vector?

Since the list can be of an arbitrary length, should it be taken out of the current tuple and returned separately? Instead of having all the values stored in a single tuple, should they be broken up into separate functions and individually returned? (i.e. one function would return the length of the list, another function returns the list itself, and a final function could return the remaining data from the tuple).

There is a lot of online resources for building python values from C to send to python, and a few references about parsing tuples, but nothing really comes up when it comes to sending a list from python to C. If anyone has experience with a similar situation, I'd be extremely grateful to understand how you accomplished it, and what I could do to solve this problem. Thanks

Comment: The link below solved the issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39063112/passing-a-python-list-to-c-function-using-the-python-c-api

Comment: Thanks for finding that. You can keep this question here, it will just be a duplicate and help searchers find the other link. :)